# Trying to split single excel file into multiple based on month using date and time column using python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file contains multiple rows with date. I want to make 12 separate file for each month. Can anyone suggest me how to do that using python?

I tried to do manually using excel sheets, However its taking long when I am using more than 100k rows.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question by adding example data and expected output , so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute and fix your indentation. Would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can try Below:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')
print(df)

#      date  data
#2019-01-14     1
#2019-02-14     2
#2019-03-14     3
#2019-03-15     4
#2019-04-16     5
#2019-07-17     6
#2019-05-18     7
#2019-06-19     8
#2019-08-20     9
#2019-09-21     0
#2019-11-22    10
#2019-01-23    12
#2019-12-29    11
#2019-12-30    13
#2019-10-01    14
#2019-10-02    15

mon = df.date.dt.to_period("M")

for i , g in df.groupby(mon):
    g.to_excel(g.date.dt.strftime('%m%y').astype(str).iloc[0] +'.xlsx',index=False)
```

**outputs in different files:**

```
      date  data
2019-01-14     1
2019-01-23    12
      date  data
2019-02-14     2
      date  data
2019-03-14     3
2019-03-15     4
      date  data
2019-04-16     5
      date  data
2019-05-18     7
      date  data
2019-06-19     8
      date  data
2019-07-17     6
      date  data
2019-08-20     9
      date  data
2019-09-21     0
      date  data
2019-10-01    14
2019-10-02    15
      date  data
2019-11-22    10
      date  data
2019-12-29    11
2019-12-30    13
```

Comment: If my answer helps you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer and also upvote